# TextView page scroll

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to create a book reader and implement the page effect. I think I can spare text in separated views and make an animation when the user wants to go to the next or previous page. The problem is that I don't find a method to spare the text correctly. I can set the max lines number for a text view, but I don't know how to get the last character from that view to calculate the text for the next view. There is a method to get from a textView only the visible text?
Is there a better solution for my ideea? Any advice will be helpfull.

Thank you!